# I was trying to insert a table and tables fields as a variable

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I was trying to insert a table and tables fields as a variable, like

```
$meta = array(
  '_wp_attached_file'=>$guid,
  '_woocommerce_exclude_image'=>'0',
  '_wp_attachment_metadata'=>''
);

foreach($meta as $key=>$value){
  mysql_query("insert into $wpdb->postmeta (`post_id`,`$key`) values('$post_id','$value')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

It gives the error

> Unknown column '_wp_attached_file' in 'field list'

How can I use the field name to insert into the table? (it is a WordPress table)

Comment: What does your table look like

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress's [`wp_postmeta` table](http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table%3a_wp_postmeta) contains only four columns:

- `meta_id`
- `post_id`
- `meta_key`
- `meta_value`

You (probably) want instead:

```
INSERT INTO $wpdb->postmeta (post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES
  ('$post_id', '$key', '$value')
```